# Is there any diffrence between hmacSha1Hex and hmacSha1?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am using org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex("secretkey", "message");

and getting a long string in output.

i tried executing org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacUtils.hmacSha1("secretkey", "message"); but facing an error

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String hmac_Sha1 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacUtils.hmacSha1("secretkey . . . '' : Typed variable declaration
```

`2016/11/29 17:09:07 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: String hmac_Sha1 = org.apache.commons.codec.`

Basically i want to know the length of output for both functions
for hmacSha1Hex output is like  HMAC SHA1 HASH: 0ff4e6a0b47baebe19c392e706fffaa13664a1df

I am expecting output like btuU9CPfMQMswNgxPIMjRkTjfks%3D difference is of length

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is in [HmacUtils JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/HmacUtils.html):

- `HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex` - is a [String](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/HmacUtils.html#hmacSha1Hex(byte[],%20byte[]))
- `HmacUtils.hmacSha1` - is a [byte[]](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/HmacUtils.html#hmacSha1(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

---

You can convert byte array to string like:

```
String s = new String (your byte array here);
```

I would also recommend using [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) instead of Beanshell, it is compliant with modern Java features and has better performance.

Comment: Can i get some links from where i can learn groovy. I am completely new to this.

Comment: In 99% of cases valid Java code will be valid Groovy code